# Get entry/node from LinkedList fastest

Tags: java, optimization, doubly-linked-list

From [LinkedList.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java/?v=source) I found this method for getting a an entry.

```
/**
 * Returns the indexed entry.
 */
private Entry<E> entry(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index+
                                            ", Size: "+size);
    Entry<E> e = header;
    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            e = e.next;
    } else {
        for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
            e = e.previous;
    }
    return e;
}
```

What bugs me is:

```
    if (index < (size >> 1))
```

Why do a bit shift operation here? Would not something like this be the optimal?

```
if (index < (size / 2)) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
        e = e.next;
} else {
    for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
        e = e.previous;
}
```

Since

```
if (index < (size / 2))
```

would promise our requested index are in the first half of the list.

Comment: size>>1 and size/2 are the same

Comment: They are equivalent. But translating size >> 1 into machine code, generates a bit shift which is faster than an integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to do a bit shift right by one in the code example: dividing by two will have the same performance, and perhaps better readability than that of a bit shift. This micro-optimization was very common in the old days of C, but now every optimizer worth its salt would do this replacement for you.

Comment: Are you sure, user3558040 answer convinces me?

Comment: @TobiasJohansson The shift is faster than division, but its compiler's job, not programmers, to make the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no. Shift operation if very fast at hardware level. It's like connecting wires (bits) and discarting the shifted ones. This only works for integer operations and "for base 2 divisions" so be aware.

Comment: OMG of course the two if staments are equal. I got my head straight a second after my post that the result are the same.

But; great input from you that it really are more fast!